# Add a line break at specific location in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a doubt of how do I add a line breaker in a js string . The below is the code :

```
{ 
  "id": 7, 
  "last": 1, 
  "name": "Customer received Email to change the password/Received. And code that customer  hasn’t requested" 
},
```

I want a line break after `password/Received`. I want the desired output as

```text
Customer received Email to change the password/Received.
And code that customer  hasn’t requested
```

Comment: Depends on where you want to output this. Is it on a webpage or any other location?

Comment: use \n in the string

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read the [tour] and also [ask].  You have received a couple of comments requesting more information.  Please update the question to answer those questions so you can receive the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the line break and cannot modify the origin of the text, then you could do something like this:

```
str = "Customer received Email to change the password/Received. And code that customer  hasn’t requested";
str.replace("password/Received. ","password/Received.\n");
```

Replace `\n` with `<br/>` if you want to output this in HTML.

Comment: I got it . Thank you. I have an other doubt with the same example , How do i add a link in the string. " this is a sample text click here to go to a website " . How do i add a link to the string " click here " ?

Comment: `str = "this is a sample text click here to go to a website";`
`str.replace("click here", "<a href='link-to-website.com'>click here</a>");`
you mean like this?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you want to output the string you need other newline options.

If you want to output this on a webpage or in an email, you can use a `<br />` tag.

```
"Customer received Email to change the password/Received.<br />And code that customer  hasn’t requested"
```

If you want to output this in an alert or in a console, you can use `\n`.

```
"Customer received Email to change the password/Received.\nAnd code that customer  hasn’t requested"
```

Comment: I have an other doubt with the same example , How do i add a link in the string. " this is a sample text click here to go to a website " . How do i add a link to the string " click here " ?